# SQL Server: IF EXISTS statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on an ***If Exists Then Update, Else Insert*** statement in SQL Server and have 2 questions.

First, I was hoping to be able to debug my statement by effectively having it perform two steps:

```
If Exists (select.....)
Print 'Record already exists'
UPDATE Tab set Col....
```

Which fails.  Is there a way to get both statements to execute or can I only have one result when If Exists returns TRUE? I tried a comma after the *PRINT* command but that made no difference.

Second, my `If Exists` query returns one record (for now).  But, running my UPDATE without a WHERE clause causes every record in the Table to be changed. I thought the UPDATE would operate only on the records returned by the `If Exists` test. Do I need to specify a WHERE clause in my UPDATE statement, much like I would if I had no `If Exists` test?

Comment: Hint:  `MERGE` can do both in one statement.

Comment: The best pattern IMHO is `UPDATE ... WHERE key = @key; IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 INSERT`. Doing an `EXISTS` first and *then* an update just makes sure you'll have one or two table accesses. The `UPDATE` accomplishes the same thing as the `EXISTS` but now it doesn't have to wait until the `EXISTS` is done to start the `UPDATE`, which encourages race conditions / deadlocks. In your case I think you are just getting caught up on syntax ... `IF` should be followed by `BEGIN / END` so SQL Server (and the reader) don't have to wonder if both the `PRINT` and the `UPDATE` should happen.

Comment: And [before you get talked into `MERGE` you should read the downsides](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).

Comment: Further, `IF EXISTS` and a subsequent `UPDATE` are completely unrelated. You need to use the same `WHERE` clause on both statements to identify the same rows, except of course if you do this in two separate statements, you need isolation in order to prevent the matching rows from changing in between. This is why it is a better pattern to just update the row(s) that match the clause, and insert only after that update is found to affect 0 rows.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - fantastic!  "IF EXISTS and a subsequent UPDATE are completely unrelated. You need to use the same WHERE clause on both statements" is just what I need to know.

Answer (score 1):

The sintax that you need should be the next:

```
if exists (select ... _your_condition_)
begin
  Print 'Record already exists'
  UPDATE Tab set Col....
end
else
begin
  Print 'New record'
  INSERT into Tab ....
end
```

Remark that without begin/end blocks, the if applies just the immediate next sentence, so the update would be done always in your example.
This is just one answer to one part of your question, which is quite misleading. If your WHERE filter has some relationship with the check that you are performing in the "if exists" sentence, we should know it exactly to know if there is a better way to resolve your query.

Comment: No. `IF EXISTS() ... UPDATE` is wasteful, it means you will always access the table twice, and you need additional control you haven't counted to prevent the underlying data from changing in between. This solves the syntax issue, to be fair, but it is not the best solution.

Comment: With the vague information provided, it’s the best effort we can do it to answer. How do I know the if exists condition has relationship with the table involved in the update?

Comment: The pattern "if exists then update else insert" implies that we're talking about the same row in all three cases. "If the row with this key exists, update it with these values; if it doesn't exist, create the row."

Comment: What about if you declare a variable with an index name, then you check if that index exists in the database. If so, you update some table with whatever related with that index (for example, you just add 1 to some table where you have the number of indexes in your db), else, you insert that information in the same, or another table. As I said, when the information is vague, all that we have are assumptions...

Comment: If that was your assumption, ask questions and clarify. It could have been if exists some user with a specific permission, or if exists some database, or if exists a linked server, etc etc. But I doubt it.

Comment: Ok @AaronBertrand... whatever. Maybe you would make the question in the same way. However, I prefer to be clearer to avoid these kind of misunderstandings.